# Android Read/Write XML file Data Error

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to create an XML file that will store the variable T1 or the TextOne EditText but I am unsure if I am doing it correctly in this code below. I am also trying to figure out how I can read the created xml file and display the T1 variable into another EditText.

```
    package com.example.treasurehunt;

    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.StringWriter;

    import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Xml;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class CreateTreasure extends Activity {
        //variables
            EditText TextOne, TextTwo, TextThree, TextFour, TextFive;
            Button SaveTreasure;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_treasure);

            TextOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextOne);
            final String T1 = TextOne.getText().toString();
            SaveTreasure = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveTreasuresButton);

            //onclick
                SaveTreasure.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        final String xmlFile="TreasureList";
                        FileOutputStream fileos;
                        try {

                            fileos = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(xmlFile, Context.MODE_APPEND);
                            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();              
                            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                            xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer);

                            xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8",true);
                            xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "TreasureList");
                            xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "TreasureOne");
                            xmlSerializer.text(T1);
                            xmlSerializer.endTag(null,"TreasureOne");
                            xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "TreasureList");
                            xmlSerializer.endDocument();
                            xmlSerializer.flush();
                            String dataWrite=writer.toString();
                            fileos.write(dataWrite.getBytes());
                            fileos.close();

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });




        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.create_treasure, menu);
            return true;
        }

}
```

Comment: I see you've used `FileOutputStream` to write to the file, have you tried `FileInputStream` to read from the file? Also, are you using an IDE to help you with brackets?

Comment: How can I use FileInputStream to read from the XML file though? Do I use xmlSerializer? As for the bracket error it says "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody" But when I enter in another Bracket, every line of code turns red :(

Comment: Fixed the bracket issue

Comment: I need an example of how to Read the XML variable T1 and display it into an EditText

Comment: This has absolutely everything you'll need: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't exactly help, there is SO much information in this page, I don't know where to begin. I just need a simple example on how to READ the variable T1 from the XML file that the code I made creates.

Comment: Begin by reading the documentation and understanding what you're doing. You know enough to create the code for writing XML to a file, so use that knowledge with the wealth code samples from that page and you shouldn't have any problems.